# Isset function not working

Tags: php, html, isset

I'm working on PHP at the moment.
I have a form seen below with a submit button.
I then created a function below also.

As you can see the first thing the function does is checked the submit button is pressed, but it goes into this if upon loading the page(i don't need to press the button), and it out puts the "Entry Submitted" p tag autmoatically, where it shouldn't even be entering the first if statement.

Any help appreciated,

```
    <p>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="100"/>
            <br />`enter code here`
        </p>
        </form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$conn_error = 'Could not connect.';
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'auser';
$mysql_pass = 'auser';

$mysql_db = 'ourwebdb';
// Connect to database

if (!@mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) || !@mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
    die ($conn_error);
}else {
    //echo 'Connected';
// Perform database insert
    $name = $_POST["Name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $teamSupported = $_POST["radioGroup"];
    $comment = $_POST["comment"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO visitors (Name, Email,[Supported Team], Comment)
              VALUES ('{$name}', '{$email}', '{$teamSupported}', '{$comment}')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result) {
        // Success
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        echo '<p> Entry Submitted</p>'; 
        // Do something
    } else {
        die ("Database query failed. ". mysql_error());
    }
        }   
}   
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Does it insert anything when the page is loaded??

Comment: It displays the "Entry Submitted" p tag and everything after that(the else/die,including the comment which is very strange)

Comment: I mean does it insert anything in the database?

Comment: Are you refreshing and re-submitting the data? This will cause the `POST` data to be sent

Comment: have you closed php tag ... as it is not shown in code ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your 1st PHP line

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit']=='Submit' ){
```

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong in your code (except cut out portion of form). so there is two possible scenario 1. you are refreshing browser url with re-submit 2. there are some onload javascript/jquery function which submit the page (form.submit()..)

Solution for 1. is easy just open the url in new tab. for scenario 2. you need to check Or submit your full code here